# Propagate bash tracing (set -x) to all child scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do I propagate bash tracing (`set -x`) to all child scripts without modifying the main script code? Is there such a way? Maybe an hidden environment variable?

Let's assume I have:

`main.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Main script"
./child.sh
```

`child.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "child script"
```

I want to call `main.sh` with some flag/environment variable/whatever that will cause `child.sh` to run with `set -e` without changing any code

Comment: `to all child scripts` Is a subshell a child script? Could you define what is a child script? Does `./script` count? Or `bash ./script`? Would `zsh ./script` count? Or `sh ./script`?

Comment: I do this as a unhidden one: Set i.e. `export TRACE=1` and in every script you want to trace, do a `[[ ${TRACE:-0} == 1 ]] && set -x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this task by creating a file `$HOME/.bash_env` like:

```sh
set -x
```

Then I added

```sh
export BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bash_env
```

to `.bash_rc`.

So, each scripts will get bash tracing enabled.